# RAILS 3 + Paperclip: cloned object steal attachments to the original one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, clone

I'm becoming mad at `Paperclip` because I need to clone an ActiveRecord object (model name is `Product`) and its attachments but the clone "steals" the original object attachments

This is what i have in my `products_controller.rb`:

```
original = Product.find_with_account(params[:id], @current_account)
clone_object = original.dup
clone_object.name = "#{original.name.split('-').first}-#{random_string}"
clone_object.product_photos = original.product_photos
clone_object.save
```

(In the middle I also add a hash to avoid naming clashes between my products).

In other words, I would like to have:

```
ORIGINAL -> [Image1, Image2 ...]
```

...Cloning...

```
ORIGINAL -> [Image1, Image2 ...]
CLONED -> [Image1Clone, Image2Clone ...]
```

Could you please point me on the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

`dup` will not duplicate the associated objects. You'll have to write your own cloning method that copies the original attachments and associates them with the duplicated Product.

Comment: @jahrichie - no idea, I didn't get any explanation :)